# how to deep clone JSON to a class

Tags: angular, typescript, class, clone

I have a JSON object and I need to parse it to a class instance. The JSON object can be really large, and I need to execute methods from the classes within.

I tried Object.assign and the Lodash API. The Lodash API is the best approach with the merge or mergeWith function, but I came to an impasse when the class property is an array. Even with the Lodash I have to initialize the properties from the class (Which I don't like but if I have to I'll do it).

I used this post [Deep Cloning in Actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800620/deep-cloning-in-actionscript)
and this [Deep clone class instance JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542052/deep-clone-es6-class-instance-javascript)

and nothing seems to do what I really want.

Here is the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1rva1k

I need to be able to execute methods from the classes within.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) is what you're looking for

Comment: @MichaelDesigaud, this works as I wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MichaelDesigaud sugested, I used the [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer).
Sorry, I don't how to mark a comment as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

"I have a json object and i need to parse it to a class instance." => have you tried JSON.parse(jsonObject) ?

Comment: this will not produce a class instance, just a javascript object

Comment: `html` <code> this.service.getComment().subscribe((comment: IComment) => {
          this.comments.push(comment);
}); </code> `html`

Comment: your code does not produce a deep class instance object